# FabricJS - Selection of polygon in non-occupied space

Tags: fabricjs

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnp7b3e9/2/) shows two shapes; a circle and a diamond (which has been drawn as a polygon):

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.add( new fabric.Circle({ 
        top: 10,  left: 10,
        radius: 15,
        fill: 'orange'
    }));


canvas.add( new fabric.Polygon(
        [
            {x: 50, y: 0},
            {x: 100, y: 100},
            {x: 50, y: 200},
            {x: 0, y: 100}
        ],{ 
        fill: 'red',
        hasBorders: false, hasControls: false, hasRotatingPoint: false, lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true,
    }));
```

I am having problems with the bounding box of the diamond which is preventing the user from selecting the circle. I would like the user to be able to select the circle by clicking on the portion of it which is visible from behind the diamond.

Is there a way to inform fabric that I only want the bounding area of a polygon to be the area that is affected by the fill colour? i.e. so it would be possible to click the circle?

Note that this is an over-simplified example of my use-case. My real-life polygon is more complicated than a simple diamond, so it would not be possible to use a rotated rectangle instead.

Answer (score 4):

This question kind old and easy but there no answer .

I just leave it here .

You need

```
perPixelTargetFind: true
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnp7b3e9/3/)

Comment: Doc reference: [http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polygon.html#perPixelTargetFind](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polygon.html#perPixelTargetFind)